# How to remove an object from an ArrayList<Class>?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I'm trying to remove the object from an ArrayList of
type Contact class. I am trying to take input from users and want to
delete that object from ArrayList

```
public class Contacts {

private String name, phoneNumber;

public Contacts(){

}

public  Contacts(String name, String phoneNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    return "Contacts{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public static Contacts createContact(String name, String phoneNumber) {
    return new Contacts(name, phoneNumber);
}
}
```

Here I tried to add objects with names and numbers and then print them and I want to delete a particular object.

```
public class Mobile {
ArrayList<Contacts> mycontacts;

public Mobile() {
    this.mycontacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
}

public void addContacts() {

    System.out.println("enter contact name");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter contact number");
    String number = sc.nextLine();

    Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, number);

    mycontacts.add(contacts);
}

public void print() {
    for (Contacts contacts : mycontacts) {
        System.out.println(contacts.getName() + "->" + contacts.getPhoneNumber());

    }


}

public String findcontact() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter contact name");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter phone number");
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, number);
    int x = mycontacts.indexOf(contacts);
    return mycontacts.get(x).getName();
}


public void remove() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter contact name");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("enter contact number");
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, number);



    Iterator<Contacts> itr = mycontacts.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){

        Contacts contacts1 = itr.next();
        System.out.println(contacts1);
        if (contacts1==contacts){
            itr.remove();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Objects should be compared with `equals`, and not with `==`.

Comment: @MCEmperor And the OP would need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the equals method on your Contacts class, something like this

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other instanceof Contract){
       Contract otherC = (Contract)other;
       return this.name.equals(otherC.name) && this.phoneNumber.equals(otherC.phoneNumber);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't my strong suit, but I think you can fix it like this:

```
Iterator<Contacts> itr = mycontacts.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){

        Contacts contacts1 = itr.next();
        System.out.println(contacts1);
        if (contacts1.getName()==contacts.getName() && contacts1.getPhoneNumber() == contacts.getPhoneNumber()){
            itr.remove();
        }

    }
```

Or simplified:

```
mycontacts.removeIf(i -> i.getName()==contacts.getName() && i.getPhoneNumber()==contacts.getPhoneNumber());
```

I think what is happening is that in this comparison: if (contacts1==contacts)

These will never be equal, as they are different objects, but they have the same values for their class variables.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-objects

> the value of those objects is not 1. Rather it is their memory addresses in the stack that are different since both objects were created using the new operator.

edit: actually, another answer showed up while I was answering, which is better. I'll leave mine up since I think I gave more explanation.

Comment: I tried to remove the object by using the index, it worked. But when I try to use remove(object o) it is not working. I think you are right "Rather it is their memory addresses in the stack that are different since both objects were created using the new operator." but there should be a way to delete objects using an object, right? Thanks for spending your valuable time. :)

Comment: The way to do that is the reply from David Lilljegren. You implemented the object, but you didn't implement what equality means to that object. By default, it assumes the same object, not an object with the same values for its class variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove an element from an ArrayList:

```
remove(Object object)
remove(int index)
```

So if you're using the `name` as the key, it could look something like:

```
public void removeContact(String name) {
    for(contact : mycontacts) {
        if(contact.name == name) {
           mycontacts.remove(contact)
       } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: I tried doing as you mentioned but the object is not getting deleted from the array. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following code, it worked. Thank you all who helped me. :)

```
for (Contacts mycontact : mycontacts) {
        if (mycontact.getName().equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("removed contact"+mycontact.getName()+"->"+mycontact.getPhoneNumber());
            mycontacts.remove(mycontact);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error deleting contact");
        }
    }
```